# Django - Return foreignkey field in string method

Tags: python, django

I want to return a foreign key field value as the unicode or string method of another model.. like this..

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    month = models.charField(max_length=20)
    .... lots more fields here

    def __str__(self):
        return related_model.Event.long_name

class Event(models.Model):
    schedule = models.Foreignkey(Schedule)
    long_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I'm not sure how to do it, because if the order of the classes is reversed then Event can't have a foreign key to Schedule.

What would be the correct way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Based on your design, one schedule can have multiple events right? So which event's long_name you intend to return? I am saying this because you are approaching it in a wrong way

Comment: of course... It needs to be a one to one relationship then?

Comment: One more question an Event needs to have a schedule right? If yes, change your models

Comment: The very underlying assumptions are not clear to you. Your intent when defining the __str__ method means that a schedule can only be related to one single event but you are using foreign key which is a one -to-many relationship.

Comment: I want Events to be able to have more than one schedule, but Schedules should only be linked to one event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that an event can have multiple schedules, which might be possibly what you want. If that is the case, change your models to this

```
class Event(models.Model):
    long_name = somefield


class Schedule(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event.long_name
```

Comment: This is of course correct, but the language is the reverse of what the models do which confuses me sometimes. Events don't have schedules at all - schedules have foreign keys to events - which is the reverse.